# Creating an Identifiable id gives inmutable warning

Tags: swift

I have the following:

```
struct myModel: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let a, b, c: String
}
```

I'm getting the following warning:

[image]

```
Immutable property will not be decoded because it is declared with an initial value which cannot be overwritten
```

I don't want to change the id once the data is refreshed, I just want to assign it once. How can I get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either declare `id` as `var` or add `CodingKeys` and omit `id`.

And please name structs and classes always with starting capital letter

```
struct MyModel: Decodable, Identifiable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case a, b, c } 

    let id = UUID()
    let a, b, c: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, `myModel` conforms to Codable for archival. When decoding, ID will be set to a new UUID instead of the UUID defined in the 'id' field in the file.

If you want to preserve IDs when decoding the structs (say, if you write it to a file and want the same ID when reading back), remove the inline initializer and write a full initializer that takes a, b, and c as arguments.

If you don't want to preserve IDs when decoding, ignoring the warning and keeping the code as-is is sufficient.